# C++ type conversion of a QObject base class to an inherited object

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance, type-conversion

I have classes `A(..):QObject(..)` and `B(..):A(..)` and create an Object A that later should be converted/extended to type B:

```
A* obA = new A(...);
obA->setMember(true);
...
#ifdef EITHER
obA = new B(...); // --> shouldBeTrue == false, see below
#else
*obA = B(...);  // --> Error - see question
#endif
bool shouldBeTrue = obA->getMember();
```

The reason for this is that I don't know the eventual type yet when creating the base object. I expected to be able to extend this object with a more refined type which then has access to the base objects members.

I understand C++ supports type conversion, but my code causes an error as it calls QObject's copy operator which intentionally was made private to prevent copying the QObject "tree".

Is this a conceptual problem? Did I get the pointers wrong?

---

Edit: added alternative line which compiles but does not do as I expect.

Comment: It should be `obA = new B(...);` and not `*obA = new B(...);`:)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of course: your fix compiles but seems to overwrite the object as the member is not `true` after attempted conversion. I have now changed the code so it properly gives the error as described.

Comment: I think you are getting the concept wrong here, you want a base class pointer point to a derived class object to achieve polymorphism, in your case you are simply overwriting a base class object with a derived class object.

Comment: I would like the derived class object to have the base class object's data by changing the base class object's type. But I could probably overload the derived constructor to accept a base class object and copy its data?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning `QObject` is conceptual error. See: [`QObject` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator)

To access existing instance of `A : public QObject` from new instance of `B : public A` you can pass pointer to existing instance to the new one in constructor.

```
A *a = new A();
B *b = new B(a);
```

In constructor of `B` you can do whatever you want with instance of `A`, e.g. copy its data part.

Comment: Thanks, but cloning was not intended and copying data from referenced object in constructor was suggested by myself in a comment.